# How to remove all value where the combination of two attributes equals a string?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to remove all references of list using LINQ where the combination of two attributes equals a string.

For instance: I have the object

```
class obj
{
  string a;
  string b;
}
```

and I have a separate string x

so I want to remove where `(a+b) == x`

Below is the example of what I want to do:

```
void Main()
{
List<telefone> phones = new List<telefone>() 
    {
        new telefone()
        {
           ddd = "21", numero="1234"
        }, 
        new telefone()
        {
           ddd = "22", 
           numero="1234"
        }
    };


List<string> newPhones = new List<string>(){"1151814088", "11996081170", "098",   "890", "99988", "6533"};

for(int i = 0; i < newPhones.Count; i++)
    {
    phones.Select(x => x.ddd + x.numero).ToList().RemoveAll(x => (x == phones[i]));
}
phones.Dump();
}

public class telefone
{
        //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
        internal string hash = String.Empty;

        public String ddd { get; set; }

        public String numero { get; set; }

        public telefone()
        {
            ddd = String.Empty;
            numero = String.Empty;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Where` + `Any`

```
var removed = phones.Where(p => !newPhones.Any(np => np == p.ddd + p.numero))
                    .ToList();
```

or even better, [`List.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) since it doesn't create a new list:

```
phones.RemoveAll(p => newPhones.Any(np => np == p.ddd + p.numero));
```

Comment: Your answer was almost right except that you put the "!" so it just removed everyone =D but it works after i remove the "!" in the
phones.RemoveAll(p => !newPhones.Any(np => np == p.ddd + p.numero));
Thanks!!!

Comment: @user1955193: Copy/paste bug from the Linq query ;)

Comment: Plus it doesnt need a loop to do it =D

Answer (score 0):

`var filteredList = initialList.Where(obj => (obj.a + obj.b) != x);`

you may want to check for null strings.